# Word Macros missing from a word doc in the network drive

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I had lot of macros/VBA scripts  for processing comments, merging etc in one few he word doc(word 2013)files on shared drive. i changed my computer and now i don't see any of the macros in those documents.

I am lost. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For macros to be available to all documents you open, they are stored in the default template for Word, `Normal.dotm`.

This file is not stored in a commonly accessible location like `My Documents` or on a shared drive. It is typically stored at the user level in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`.

So, when you changed computers, you probably copied all your documents but didn't know to get this file. If your old computer is still available, copy this file over and you should see your macros.